# Use a button to load more data from the server without refresh the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

My server load articles from a xml, and send them to my view. 
I'd like to only send some articles instead, not all of them, and provide to the user a button to load more articles.
But how can I send these new data to my view without refreshing the page, is it possible to only update the Model?

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Article>), new XmlRootAttribute("Articles"));
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"/articles/articles.xml"))
            {
                articles = (List<Article>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            return View(articles);
        }


<div id="articles">
    @foreach (Article art in Model)
    {
        var articleImage = "/images/articles/" + art.Image + ".jpg";
        <article>
            <div class="article_title_and_date">
                <h2 class="article_title">@art.Title</h2>
                <p class="article_date">@art.Date</p>
            </div>
            <img src="@Url.Content(articleImage)" alt="image">
            <p>
                @art.Text
            </p>
        </article>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to implement some JavaScript to talk to your server via an API. Here's a basic example of getting some different data from a server on each click of the button.

```js
var postNumber = 1;

document.getElementById('getNextPost').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var currentPost = document.getElementById('currentPost');
  var url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postNumber++}`;

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => currentPost.innerHTML = json.body)
})
```

```html
<div id="currentPost">Some static content from the server</div>
<button id="getNextPost">Get Next Post</button>
```

This example uses a JSON endpoint; however, you can read values from an XML endpoint by using `window.DOMParser` inside the `.then()`

```
new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml")
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I used jquerry and called there a function from my controller which return a string. Then I add it as html to my articles.

`code`<script>
    
    var articlesLoaded = 5;

    $(document).on('click', '#getNextArticles', function () {
        $.get("/Home/GetMoreArticles", { articlesLoaded: articlesLoaded }, function (data) {
            var currentPost = document.getElementById('articles');
            currentPost.innerHTML += data;

            articlesLoaded += 5;
        });
    });
</script>`code`

Comment: @BaptisteOuille honestly, your code is 99% Vanilla JavaScript, I’d just ditch jQuery